# Div animation will not pan downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to animate this div to slide down when a button is clicked, but the animation is all messed up. It glitches when the div is opening or closing.

I've tried adding position:relative and overflow:hidden to it, but it doesn't seem to be working (bear in mind i'm also using Bootstrap).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".faqOuter").click(function(){
        $(".faqInner").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
p{
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: 0 !important;
}

.faqOuter{
 color: white;
 background-color: #262626;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px !important;
 height: 30px;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #262626;
 padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.faqInner{
 padding: 40px 35px 40px 40px !important;
 position: relative !important;
 border: solid;
 border-color: #F3F3F3;
 display: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="faqOuter col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">Trial One Bar</h4>
   <div class="faqInner col-md-12">
    <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil expetendis in mei.</p>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `!important` from padding as it's making the calculation of height during the transition messy.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faqOuter").click(function() {
    $(".faqInner").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.faqOuter {
  color: white;
  background-color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #262626;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.faqInner {
  padding: 40px 35px 40px 40px;
  border: solid;
  display: none;
  border-color: #F3F3F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="faqOuter col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">Trial One Bar</h4>
<div class="faqInner col-md-12">
  <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil expetendis in mei.</p>
</div>
```